# Setting up HTTP connection and getting response in Android Emulator

Tags: android, http, android-emulator

I have an android application that parses the HTML content and displays the required tag. 
It is working fine for the hardcoded HTML code.

But when I set up a HTTP connection for a URL, then it is not working in Emulator.

Let me know how to set up an HTTP connection in android and see the response in Emulator.

I want to give that response as an input to the parser.

I want it working and parsing in Emulator iteself.

The error that I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ltil.HtmlContentParser.main(HtmlContentParser.java:31)
```

Comment: What does the LogCat output say?

Comment: Hi. What exactly is the problem when you set up an HTTP connection? What is the error?

Comment: What's the host in your URL: Something on the Internet or a private host/IP? Are you able to browse the Internet from your emulator using the built-in web browser? Is there a stacktrace in your `logcat` output?

Comment: Without LogCat, we can't say otherwise we can throw stones in air.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? If yes, you have to give manually the proxy config to the emulator.

Comment: Let me know how to manually give the proxy config and Yes I am covered under a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting the emulator with the option `-http-proxy <proxy>` allows you to specify a proxy